# Set a custom install directory when making a deb package with fpm

Tags: django, packaging, devops, deb, fpm

I'm using fpm to create a deb package, but when I install that deb package, it is installed into the wrong location, my fpm command is:

```
fpm -f -s "dir" -t "deb" -a "all" -n "my_project" -v 1 -C "/tmp/tmpjWTuVp" /tmp/tmpjWTuVp/my_project
```

The folder i want to package up exists at `/tmp/tmpjWTuVp/my_project`, but every time i install it with:

```
dpkg -i my_package.deb
```

it installs it into `/tmp/tmpjWTuVp/my_project`, ideally i'd like it to install into `/var/lib/my_project`. I have tried `--installdir` and `--root` with my `dpkg` command, but it complains with `cannot access archive: No such file or directory`

Other information:

- I'm installing onto an ubuntu box
- I'm very new to deb packaging, so may have missed something obvious
- I'm not bound to `fpm` and happy to hear other viable suggestions
- inside `my_project` is a python `virtualenv` and my django project

Answer (score 3):

I have randomly found the answer to this immediately after writing this question...

basically the last, unnamed argument within the fpm command can contain an equals separator which defines the directory to come from, and to install to, so the command I ended up using was:

```
fpm -f -s "dir" -t "deb" -a "all" -n "my_project" -v 1 -C "/tmp/tmpjWTuVp" my_project=/var/lib/my_project
```

Notice the `my_project=/var/lib/my_project`, the left side is the directory name of my project (relative, because I used `-C` to change directory to `/tmp/tmpjWTuVp` before looking for packages) and on the right side is where I want to install to on the remote machine...